# Grails 4 how to test if domain class PersistentProperty is an assocation?

Tags: grails, dns, persistent

In earlier versions of Grails 3 there was a property "GrailsDomainClassProperty.association". I could use this to test whether a property was part of an association.  In Grails 4 how do I use PersistentProperty to find this out?  Is a property a simple type or an association - one-to-one, one-to-many, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is to get the PersistentEntity.associations list and check there as to whether an arbitrary property is in fact an assocation.  There may be a better answer but that is what I'm going with.

Comment: "There may be a better answer but that is what I'm going with." - If that is the case, you should mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the property is an instance of
`org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.types.Association`